# How to port DeltaSpike @WindowScoped annotated beans to the Spring framework?

Tags: spring, jsf, deltaspike

I want to port an older CDI application using deltaspike, jsf, and primefaces to the spring framework. That means the CDI and deltaspike needs to be replaced by some spring code. What is the best approach to convert beans that are annotated with @WindowScoped? These are bound to the current browser window or tab. There is no such scope in spring web. Neither request scope nor session scope is suitable for multiple browser windows.

Comment: Check out http://joinfaces.org/

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: Does joinfaces have a windowscoped? Don't see it

Comment: Joinfaces does not know DeltaSpike. But you could use the IceFaces Window Scope

Comment: You can implement your own WindowScope in Spring based on FacesContext#getExternalContext#getClientWindow#getId
I dont have an example and also dont think someone implemented it already.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to joinfaces and for the hint with getClientWindow. Unfortunately joinfaces does not implement windowscoped from deltaspike out of the box.